# Moving files in windows environment to folders that have part of the file name

Tags: batch-file

I have files like these in my master folder. The file name to the hyphen is the person's name:

> 1. Ran Perhar-Training Records.pdf
> 2. Ran Perhar-Certificates achieved.docx
> 3. Ran Perhar-Travel Records.xlsx
> 4. Dove John-Training Records.pdf
> 5. Dove John-Certificates achieved.docx
> 6. Dove John-Travel Records.xlsx

There are 4 - 5 files per person, about 200 persons in all.

I want to: Create a folder for each person based on name. For example: Ran Perhar.  If this folder does not exist create it. If it exists, I want to move all files that have Ran Perhar before the hyphen moved into Ran Perhar folder. Same with Dove John, and so on and so forth.

All files exist in the same master folder and the individual folders will be created within the same folder.

Comment: Do you want the name-based folders to be subfolders of the master directory?

Comment: Do you accept PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested :

```
@echo off

pushd "c:\persons"

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /a:-d /b *') do (
   md "%%~a" >nul 2>nul
   move "%%~a%%~b" "%%~a\" /y
)
```

Comment: The name based folders will be created in a folder called Records which will be in the same directory as files like Ran Perhar-Training records.

Comment: This solution worked. I did some changes once I understood the format/syntax. Wanted to thank from the bottom of my heart. Thank you npoc maka. This gave me an answer and inspiration to learn. I love to learn batch programming but am not aware of any resources online or books. Any suggestions? Please let me know. For now we can consider this question to be answered and CLOSED. Thanks to Stack Overflow's combined genius. All be well and take care.

Comment: @RanPerhar you can click on the tick bellow the answer points to accept it.As for the tutorials - good starting point is this : http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php  - the info is a little bit  outdated but is still stable introduction to batch files. This http://ss64.com/nt/ is probably the best reference for batch commands , but sometimes it lacks of details. Here http://www.dostips.com/ you can find a nice ready to use functions and it has the most viable batch-script community.

Comment: npocmaka, what tick am I expected to click. Sorry, I am lost on this. Thank you for the turtorial and further knowledge suggestions. Ran Perhar